# using STL in lex/flex code

Tags: c++, stl, yacc, flex-lexer

I am trying to implement a prototype of assembly language parser using lex/flex and yacc/bison. I want to create a symbol table which is a C++ STL `vector` of a `struct`. However, I am a newbie about lex and just know that as lex generates C code, I guess the symbol table can't be used directly in lex file as it C doesn't have STL.

Is there a way that can help me to manipulate vector symbol table from lex and access it from yacc code?

Thanks..

Comment: I retagged the post.  Flex-lexer is for the lexical analyzer... [it even says so in the "hover details" of the Flex tag now

Comment: If I recall correctly, the output from (most versions of) Flex can be compiled as C++.

Comment: As long as you compile with the g++ compiler. The code will be treated as a C++ source file (even if the extension on the file is *.c). If you want to force the output file to have (*.cpp) extension you can use the `-o` flag with `flex`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue while building a custom compiler. There are few approaches:

- Create a separate c++ file, implement function in c++ and export it to C:

  extern "C" {
      void f() {
          // C++ code here
      }
  }

now you can invoke it from lex/yacc generated code.

- Generate c++ code in flex/bison, then you can directly write C++ code in grammars.
- You still can include C++ code in grammar, but that's not a good idea for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

flex and bison have C++-friendly equivalents, flex++ and bison++.  The manual pages for those might be helpful for you.

flex++ is simply flex which outputs C++ code.  bison++ is a separate project, based on bison, which generates C++ code.